# How to check action permission from url in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that I want to check action permission when URL change.

For example, I have an action that uses to change password users. when the user clicks it, first send authorize code to the user, then navigate the user to change password action.

But if the user put action name in URL directly, the authorize action is not called.

How can I check action permission when the user enters it directly in the URL?

Comment: How did you use authorize code in change password action?

Answer (score 0):

For checking the permisson before return change password view, you could try to check the authorize code in action and return `ForbidResult` like

```
public IActionResult ChangePassword()
{
    if (!HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("authorize", out StringValues code))
    {
        return new ForbidResult();
    }
    return View();
}
```

Or, you could try [Action filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.0#action-filters)